# Access Master DB Tables from User Database in SQL AZURE

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I am trying to access `sys.SQL_Logins` on Master DB from a User Database so that I could join `sys.sql_logins` with `sys.sysusers`.

**UserDatabase**

```
SELECT      DP.NAME, DP.sid, SU.sid
FROM        sys.sql_logins  DP
INNER JOIN  SYS.sysusers SU
ON      DP.name=SU.name
```

In Azure I am not able to do this, since I am not able to call master DB from `UserDatbase`. My objective was to compare SID of `sys.sql_logins`  with `sys.sqlusers` from User Database.

Is there any way I could join these two tables in Azure.

Comment: What is the purpose? You should be using contained database users if you're using Azure SQL. If you connect as an admin and explicitly connect to master you can connect but you are missing something about the PaaS offering if you think you need to do this.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to compare SID's from logins[which exits in master] to User Database. I am facing an issue where some logins SID and users SID's are incorrect.

Comment: Why didn't you use database contained users in the first place? What actual issue are you having? can some people not login?

Answer (score 0):

You can only execute queries against a single database. However, you can set up an external table to point to the master database views. This code should get you there:

```
CREATE MASTER KEY;  -- if your DB doesn't already have one
GO

CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL AccessToMaster
WITH IDENTITY = 'yourmasterlogin', SECRET = 'yourpassword'; --TODO set a login name and password that can access the master database
GO

CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE MasterDatabase
WITH
(
    TYPE = RDBMS,
    LOCATION = N'yourserver.database.windows.net',  --TODO replace your server name
    DATABASE_NAME = N'master',
    CREDENTIAL = AccessToMaster
);
GO

CREATE SCHEMA MasterDB AUTHORIZATION dbo;
GO

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE MasterDB.sql_logins
(
    [name] sysname, 
    principal_id int, 
    [sid] varbinary(85), 
    [is_disabled] bit 
)
WITH
(
  DATA_SOURCE = MasterDatabase,
  SCHEMA_NAME = 'sys',
  OBJECT_NAME = 'sql_logins'
);
GO

SELECT * FROM MasterDB.sql_logins;
GO
```